# Converting quarters, dimes, and pennies to dollars and cents in Haskell

Tags: haskell, converters

I'm trying to convert quarters, dimes, and pennies to dollars and cents, but I can't seem to get the code to run.

I tried this code:

```
-- Declaration
toCents :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
toDollar :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int

-- Definition
toCents quarter dime penny  = quarter*25 + dime*10 + penny
toDollar quarter dime penny = (toCents quarter dime penny) / 100) - ((toCents quarter dime penny mod 100) / 100)

main :: IO()
main = do
 let quarter = 12
 let dime = 67
 let penny = 43
 let sumDollar = toDollar quarter dime penny
 let sumCents = toCents quarter dime penny - (toDollar quarter dime penny) * 100
 print ("Conversion of " ++ show quarter ++ " quarters, " ++ show dime ++ " dimes, and " ++ show penny ++ " pennies to dollars and cents:")
 print(sumDollar ++ " dollars and " ++ sumCents ++ " cents.")
```

And it resulted to this error:

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( main.hs, main.o )
main.hs:7:68: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘(Integer -> Integer -> Integer)
                                    -> Integer -> Int’
                  with actual type ‘Int’
    • The function ‘toCents’ is applied to five arguments,
      but its type ‘Int -> Int -> Int -> Int’ has only three
      In the first argument of ‘(/)’, namely
        ‘(toCents quarter dime penny mod 100)’
      In the second argument of ‘(-)’, namely
        ‘((toCents quarter dime penny mod 100) / 100)’
  |
7 | toDollar quarter dime penny = (toCents quarter dime penny / 100) - ((toCents quarter dime penny mod 100) / 100)
  |                                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
main.hs:17:8: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘[Char]’ with actual type ‘Int’
    • In the first argument of ‘(++)’, namely ‘sumDollar’
      In the first argument of ‘print’, namely
        ‘(sumDollar ++ " dollars and " ++ sumCents ++ " cents.")’
      In a stmt of a 'do' block:
        print (sumDollar ++ " dollars and " ++ sumCents ++ " cents.")
   |
17 |  print(sumDollar ++ " dollars and " ++ sumCents ++ " cents.")
   |        ^^^^^^^^^
main.hs:17:40: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘[Char]’ with actual type ‘Int’
    • In the first argument of ‘(++)’, namely ‘sumCents’
      In the second argument of ‘(++)’, namely ‘sumCents ++ " cents."’
      In the second argument of ‘(++)’, namely
        ‘" dollars and " ++ sumCents ++ " cents."’
   |
17 |  print(sumDollar ++ " dollars and " ++ sumCents ++ " cents.")
   |
```

Comment: You probably want: `toCents quarter dime (mod penny 100)` - missing left parenthesis. Note that library function [`divMod`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:divMod) could be useful. Above all, never ever allow a line of code to get so long that you can't see its rightmost end without losing sight of the leftmost part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression `toCents quarter dime penny mod 100` is parsed as

```
     ((((toCents quarter) dime) penny) mod) 100
```

or

```
      ( ( ( (toCents quarter
            ) dime
          ) penny
        ) mod
      ) 100
```

That looks completely weird, though it's not *that* weird if you keep in mind how currying works: it corresponds to, in an uncurried language,

```
      toCents(quarter, dime, penny, mod, 100)
```

Which is of course still nonsense though: you're feeding `mod` as an argument to the function `toCents`, instead of using it right there as an operator. Infix operators with letter names must be written in backticks to apply them, like `` 37`mod`4 ``, which is the same as `mod 37 4`. Infix operators always bind weaker than prefix function application, so if you had written

```
  toCents quarter dime penny `mod` 100
```

then this would have parsed as

```
  mod (toCents quarter dime penny) 100
```

which is probably what you intended. That does however not mean it's good for the task. What you're doing with

```
    foo/100 - (foo`mod`100)/100
```

is a very roundabout attempt of implementing simple *round-to-negative integer division*.

It kind of works in Python, but even there it doesn't really do what it should: Python automatically converts the integers `foo` and `100` to floats to perform the division, then subtracts to floats from each other and the result is still a float though it happens to have zero fractional part.

Haskell doesn't even allow this mess to happen: it will complain that the `/` operator is not available on integers. You you really wanted that, you would have to explicitly convert to floats.

You **don't** want that though: you should simply use [the built-in integer division operator](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:div) instead

```
toDollar quarter dime penny = toCents quarter dime penny `div` 100
```

...Assuming it should really have round-to-negative behaviour.

Even better would be to structure your code and data properly, which would avoid both redundant computations and cryptic `Int -> Int -> ...` signatures:

```
data DollarValue = DollarValue {
       dollarPartVal, centPartVal :: Int
     }
data DollarCoins = DollarCoins {
       quarterCoinCount, dimeCoinCount, pennyCoinCount :: Int
     }

coinsValue :: DollarCoins -> DollarValue
coinsValue (DollarCoins q d p) = DollarValue dollars cents
 where (dollars, cents) = (25*q + 10*d + p)`divMod`100

import Text.Printf

main = do
   let quarter = 12
       dime = 67
       penny = 43
   let DollarValue sumDollars sumCents
        = coinsValue $ DollarCoins quarter dime penny
   printf
    "Conversion of %i quarters, %i dimes, and %i pennies: %i dollars and %i cents.\n"
                   quarter      dime          penny       sumDollars     sumCents
```